# Where should ongoing time based calculations go in cocos2D?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

> I want to constantly advance the
>   screen (moving level) and have bad
>   guys appear and attack from various
>   sides of the player sprite. This will
>   require ongoing modification of the
>   values of the objects on the layer as
>   well as creation and destruction of
>   them.

There is an AppDelegate, it fires up the CCDirector for HelloWorldLayer scene.

HellowWorldLayer.m creates the other things that it shows such as textures and sprites.

Now, should I add logic to HelloWorldLayer to keep track of things and generate/move monsters, keep track of daytime and nighttime triggers? Or should I create another object?

Would an object owned by HelloWorldLayer be able to access the HelloWorldLayer parent object and modify the things on display and read from them?

Should I create a new Object that handles this outside of HelloWorldLayer and instantiate it? If so, would it be able to have access to HelloWorldLayer?

Inside of HelloWorldLayer there is the init() method that creates everything but I kind of doubt I should put logic in there.

**TL;RD: Into which object should I put the 'game loop' logic code?**

Answer (score 1):

I put my game loop code into the `CCScene` object, which is the parent of your `HelloWorldLayer`.

At first I had the game loop inside of the main game `CCLayer`, but as I began to add more and more layers, trying to get objects from the game layer to other layers, such as the UI layer, it became convoluted.

It seems a lot cleaner since I moved it into the `CCScene`, which now also handles any of the shared dependencies between the various layers.

I also opted to put it into the `CCScene`, as opposed to a brand new class for this purpose, because I wanted to still be able to use the cocos2d scheduler for firing off each iteration of the loop... since `CCScene` is still just a `CCNode`, it has access to this scheduler.